# How to get complete server error log in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am very new to React and JavaScript apps. I am finding it very difficult to catch Next.js API errors. I am only getting `Internal Server Error` and nothing else (means why the Internal Server Error occurred)!

How can I get the complete server error log of Next.js API? I even tried a catch block but it's not giving the expected output `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Add logging to your server side code and inspect the server output when you hit the API endpoint from the frontend.

Comment: I am using backend and fronent in the same next js app

Comment: Look for the logs in the terminal window where you started the server, not in the browser's console.

Comment: @juliomalves thank you so much.. plz post this as an answer.. you have saved me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Next.js, code that runs on the server-side (`getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, API routes) happens on the terminal where you first started the server.

Any errors or logs to the console will be visible on the terminal window rather than the browser's console.

Comment: I have an array inside my error? How do i log that? It appears as `result: { errors: [Array] }`

Comment: @LeonardoViada Do `console.log(result.errors)` directly.

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves . In my case - in webstorm - running next dev in debug mode (bug icon) logged the whole array.