# TypeError: Failed to fetch next js

Tags: next.js

When trying to get data in next js, the server does not return anything at all, the console is empty, tell me, please, what could be wrong?

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
   const res = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/manga');
   const data = await res.json();

  console.log('data >>>', data);

  return {
    props: {
      manga: data,
    },
  };
```

};

Comment: Your code seemed to be valid, so i tried in another project and it seems to work well. just to confirm, that console log will not show up in your browser but rather in your terminal where you ran the yarn dev command.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to get complete server error log in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398007/how-to-get-complete-server-error-log-in-next-js)?